# Table-like layouts in html 5 with broad browser support

Tags: css, html, layout

I want to know what reliable options are available in css for imitating basic <table>-like layouts with broad browser support.

Here is a straightforward example using actual tables.

Is there a better way to do this using CSS that also works in recent imperfect browsers? (ie10/ie11+)

```css
table tr td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>apple</td>
    <td><input type="text" style="width:200px"></td>
    <td rowspan="4" valign="top" style="padding-left:50px;">
      checkboxes:<br>
      <input type="checkbox"> hello<br>
      <input type="checkbox"> world<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>banana</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cherry</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use divs and `display: table`, `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell`.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 grid layout will do the trick.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Be careful about compatibility, though.

https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20grid%20layout